# For loop parent binding for dynamic children actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation binding click events to the static parent for dynamically added children which is not working.  My original post contained example code which seemed to reproduce the problem but was mistakenly using an id in the dynamic content in stead of the class.

This update more accurately represents the actual implementation however I am unable to reproduce the problem in this example.

```
<div id="page">

  <div id="section-0" class="container">
    <span>section 0</span>
    <div id="section-actions">
      <button class="button action-zero">zero</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="section-1" class="container">
    <span>section 1</span>
    <div class="section-actions"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="section-2" class="container">
    <span>section 2</span>
    <div class="section-actions"></div>
  </div>

<script>
action_array = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

section_actions = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

add_section_actions();
bind_actions();

function add_section_actions() {
  for (var s = 1; s <= 2; s++) { // for sections 1 and 2
    var actions_html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < section_actions.length; i++) { // for all the actions
      var action = section_actions[i];
      actions_html = actions_html + '<button class="action-' + action + '">' + action + '</button>';
    }
    $('#section-'+s+' .section-actions').html(actions_html);
  }
}

function bind_actions() {
  //console.log('bind_actions called');
  for (var i = 0; i < action_array.length; i++) {
    //console.log(i);
    var action = action_array[i];
    //console.log('attempting to bind action for '+action);
    $('#page').on('click', '.action-' + action, function() {
      var this_container = $(this).closest('.container');
      var this_container_id = this_container.attr('id');
      console.log('this_container_id: ' + this_container_id);
    });

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add the class `class="action-'+action+'"` to your buttons

```
actions_html = actions_html + '<button class="action-'+action+'" id="section-2-button-' + action + '">' + action + '</button>';
```

***Demo***

```js
action_array = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

section_two_actions = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

add_section_two_actions();
bind_actions();

function add_section_two_actions() {
  var actions_html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < section_two_actions.length; i++) {
    var action = section_two_actions[i];
    //console.log('adding section 2 action: '+action);
    actions_html = actions_html + '<button class="action-'+action+'" id="section-2-button-' + action + '">' + action + '</button>';
  }
  $('#section-2-actions').html(actions_html);
}

function bind_actions() {
  //console.log('bind_actions called');
  for (var i = 0; i < action_array.length; i++) {
    //console.log(i);
    var action = action_array[i];
    //console.log('attempting to bind action for '+action);
    $('#page').on('click', '.action-' + action, function() {
      var this_container = $(this).closest('.container');
      var this_container_id = this_container.attr('id');
      console.log('this_container_id: ' + this_container_id);
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="section-0" class="container">
    <span>section 0</span>
    <div id="section-0-actions">
      <button class="button action-zero">zero</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section-1" class="container">
    <span>section 1</span>
    <div id="section-1-actions">
      <button class="button action-one">one</button>
      <button class="button action-two">two</button>
      <button class="button action-three">three</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section-2" class="container">
    <span>section 2</span>
    <div id="section-2-actions"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you.  shoot though, I thought I duplicated the problem here but the actual implementation actually only uses the classes.  I'll have to dig deeper.